# Update a table with results from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-update

Currently using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (Management Studio), looking to update a column in a table with a query which uses data from another table.

This is the query I am running:

```
SELECT        
    tblGeneralVehicleInformation.EngineerVehicleReg, tblModel.Model_ID, 
    tblModel.VanOrCar, tblModel.Model, tblMake.Make_ID, 
    tblMake.WarrantyCars, tblMake.WarrantyVans, 
    tblMake.WarrantyCarMonths, tblMake.WarrantyVanMonths, 
    tblGeneralVehicleInformation.PurchaseDate, 
    tblGeneralVehicleInformation.Mileage
FROM            
    tblGeneralVehicleInformation 
INNER JOIN
    tblModel ON tblGeneralVehicleInformation.Model_IDFK = tblModel.Model_ID 
INNER JOIN
    tblMake ON tblGeneralVehicleInformation.Make_IDFK = tblMake.Make_ID


UPDATE dbo.tblGeneralVehicleInformation
SET WarrantyId = '1'  
WHERE (tblModel.VanOrCar = N'Van') 
  AND (Mileage > WarrantyVans) 
  AND (DateDiff("M",PurchaseDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > WarrantyVanMonths)
```

Should this work or are you not able to have a query like the above within the `UPDATE` statement?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine both into a single statement.  I would also advise you start using table aliases to make your code a little more readable...

```
UPDATE v
SET WarrantyId = '1'
FROM tblGeneralVehicleInformation v
    INNER JOIN tblModel mo
       ON v.Model_IDFK = mo.Model_ID 
    INNER JOIN tblMake ma
       ON v.Make_IDFK = ma.Make_ID
WHERE (mo.VanOrCar = N'Van') 
  AND (Mileage > WarrantyVans) 
  AND (DateDiff("M",PurchaseDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > WarrantyVanMonths)
```